# Analytic solution of coupled nonlinear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I would like to solve the following differential equation system,

$$ \frac{dx}{dt} = C_{1}\cdot x(t) + C_{2}\cdot x(t)^{2} +C_{3}\cdot x(t)\cdot y(t)\\
\frac{dy}{dt} = C_{4}\cdot y(t) + C_{5}\cdot y(t)^{2} +C_{6}\cdot x(t)\cdot y(t)$$

where $$C_{1},C_{2},C_{3},C_{4},C_{5},C_{6} $$ are constants and the initial conditions are given, $$ x(t=0) = xt_{0}\qquad y(t=0) = yt_{0}$$ 
and the values of the variables in equilibrium when $$ \frac{dx}{dt} = 0 \qquad \frac{dy}{dt} = 0 $$
are also given: $$ x_{0} = 0 \qquad y_{0} = 0$$

Could someone give me any advise or method to help me find the analytic solution of x(t), y(t).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is a quite interesting problem. I'm afraid that there is no analytical solution but for some special cases (perhaps for $C_2=C_3=C_5=C_6=0$). Since the RHS of your equations is not Lipschitz continuous for all $t \in R$, the Picard-Lindelöf theorem can not ensure uniqueness (nor existence) for solutions for infinite time. Considering non uniqueness, but existence, maybe it means that there is some stationary solution for infinite $t$ in the form of an attractor to which more then one solution converges.

Comment: I'm wondering if there's a way to represent this in a vectorized format, with some matrix on the RHS that you could diagonalize. That is, the RHS looks like you might be able to do a change of variable and uncouple it by finding principle components or something like that.

Comment: @rafa11111 The RHS is locally Lipschitz in the variables $x,y$. Existence and uniqueness of a _local_ solution is guaranteed.

Comment: So far I've tried to express explicitly the y(t) variable from the first equation then paste it into the second equation by putting it formally to the RHS and calculating the LHS which is the derivative of y(t).

Comment: @JuliánAguirre Precisely, but is my conclusion about a possible attractor flawed?

Comment: $(0,0)$ is an equilibrium point. Its character (sink, source, saddle,...) will depend on the constants $C_i$, and can be found by linearization. Also, depending on the values of the constants, there may be more equilibria.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre I've tried the linearization also, and I've found the four fix points. But in these cases the solution is a sum of two exponential function and it doesen't fit to my curve which comes from a numerical solution.

Comment: Please document what you tried and how the approximation by linearization fits or does not fit. Note that linearization only makes claims on the behavior very close to the stationary points.

Comment: Such systems are called [generalized Lotka-Volterra equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Lotka%E2%80%93Volterra_equation), and there is vast literature on them.  For starters, see the monograph by Hofbauer and Sigmund.

Comment: Already the (non generalized) Lotka-Volterra systems do not have explicit solutions in the sense that one cannot write down explicit formulas for $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ as functions of $t$. But much is known, for example, that $(x(t),y(t))$ stays on a curve of equation $$H(x,y)=H(x_0,y_0)$$ for some explicit function $H$. As @user539887 said, it seems mandatory at this point to read at least part of the relevant literature.